# Why does my Cherokee PA28-180 Lycoming motor run hot?

Tags: general-aviation, engine, piston-engine

Regarding my Cherokee PA28-180. Could you please explain me why my new Lycoming engine with 800 hrs runs hot?

1. My mechanic says that the EGT #2 should be around 1350 degrees. The minute you lean the fuel at cruise alt, you have to richen it back up to stay < 1350 degrees.
2. During 1800 rpm run-up & during cruise speed of 135 mph, the oil pressure is just barely under the red line & it stays there for the duration of the flight. My mechanic says that's ok for this motor.
3. My mechanic says that we are to stay away from the 2100 rpm to 2400 rpm range. That's red line for our motor. Why?

Comment: also I've been leaning using the lean-rpm drop-richen back up until motor is running smooth. How do you lean utilizing the EGT gauge? My mechanic says to fly w/ the #2 cylinder <1350 degrees.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we aren't mechanics and, even if we were, we couldn't give advice on an engine we've not seen.

Comment: This guy has a question that can be answered.  The answer isn't a matter of opinion and can be applied to virtually every common aircraft engine.  How is this too broad??

Answer (score 3):

You say it runs hot.  Why do you say that?  Is the oil temp pushing redline?  Do you have a CHT gauge?

1. EGT alone means nothing. Don't use it to set cruise settings.  What if the probes aren't all set 5" (or whatever) from the exhaust valve? What if they're only 3"?  Or 7"?  Or staggered between 3" and 7"?  Point is, the EGT number is just a repeatable value.  Don't think of it as a temperature.  Your Archer with probes 5" from the exhaust valve may read 1350° at full rich takeoff from sea level.  Your hangar mate with an identical plane (except for having probes only 3" from the valves) might see 1420° at the exact same setting.  Once you understand that EGTs *aren't really* temperatures and are merely reference numbers (or some type of "heat unit that isn't 'temperature'") the whole thing makes more sense.

   Also, if you just have a single point EGT then just pretend it's not there and simply use the POH.  Single point EGTs tend to do more harm than good, especially if they're reading the confluence of two cylinder exhausts.  What possible useful information can you glean from an averaged temperature from half the cylinders on your engine, especially if it's carbureted?!?!
2. Does your mechanic know (and can he explain) *why* his tips make sense?  I'd love to hear his reasoning because I don't think it'll make sense.
3. You either have a bad oil pressure gauge or your pressure it too low.  *Fix that.*  A good gauge running below red line is very bad.  A bad gauge is better, but still bad.  The limits are not arbitrary.
4. Engine RPM limits are important.  Does Lyc publish a limitation between those RPMs for your specific engine suffix and serial number range?  If the limitation is an AD, has it been complied with and the limitation removed?

   Running your engine at redline will not hurt anything *provided* the engine does not have a limitation (in the limitation section of the POH) on max RPM.  I know it feels right to "baby" the engine but there is no practical effect unless a limitation exists.  Note that "recommended procedures" are not "limitations."

I'd seriously consider talking with another mechanic if that's at all practical.  Your mechanic may be an airframe god but his advice regarding engines would have me shopping for a new IA.

Answer (score 0):

so you have two very good questions:

1)1350 egt, look up the egt limits from Lycoming for the correct engine model.  What you should be looking with most non-turbo charged engines from an operations stand point would be - set cruise power, very slowly lean to peak and then enrichen the mixture until you are 50-100 degrees rich of peak. Please be aware that leaning the engine is something that is condition specific (OAT, Density Alt, Power Setting, IAS) Changes to any of these can and will change your EGT.  This will typically give you a safe margin and not have the engine detonating or running too hot.  I have not seen a Lycoming where the egt at 1350 is outside of normal operating temp however in some conditions 1350 could be pushing you close to peak.   Check with Lycoming on your model engine just to be sure.

2) RPM is not limited to 2400 on the o-360 in the Piper PA-28.   RPM range is limited on some of the year models where you are not supposed to run the airplane in the 2100-2400 range due to a vibration issue with the standard propeller / engine combination. The performance section of your POH will give you % hp verses RPM at specific altitudes.